# Angularjs - Dropdown - check if no value selected

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to verify if an option other then the default display has been selected.  I can not seem to access/verify the empty value for the default case.

I never get to the inner if, I have confirmed I get past the outer. So I'm sure the issue is with my method of accessing 'program_id' I'm just hitting a wall.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

programIdsDropDown is JSON populated from a DB.

html

```
<select
    name="program_id"
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="formData.program_id"
    ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in programIdsDropDown"
>
<option value="">Please select..</option>
</select>
<div ng-show="mainForm.$submitted">
<span class="text-danger" ng-show="shouldChangeProgram()">Please select a Program.<br /></span>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.shouldChangeProgram = function() {
var result = false;

if($scope.formData.status == 'closed')
{
    if($scope.formData.program_id == '')
    {
        result = true;
    }
}

$scope.mainForm.status.$setValidity('shouldChangeProgram', !result);

return result;
};
```

Comment: Inside your first if, what do you get if you `console.log($scope.formData.status)`? Also, you can add the `required` attribute on your `<select>` and form validation (assuming this is wrapped in a `<form>` or `<ng-form>` tag) will set the `$valid` property to false which you could then simply use.

Comment: @Lex
I get closed as I expect.  The dropdown is only required in the state that another dropdown is chosen as closed.  It is not required when the the other dropdown is in any other non-closed state.

Comment: Also, it's just in a bootstrap div

     <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="control-label col-xs-4">Program</div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">

Comment: Oops, I meant `console.log($scope.formData.program_id)`. It must be something other than an empty string if that if statement is not evaluating to true.

Comment: That type of conditional requirement is exactly what the `ng-required` directive is for. A value for the control will only be required if the expression in `ng-required` evaluates to true. You really should consider using a `<form>` and taking advantage of the validation that Angular provides. It is much more robust than writing a bunch of code in your controllers.

Comment: @Lex
Thanks for the advice and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should better use :

```
if(!$scope.formData.program_id) {
   result = true;
}
```

If problem insists you should check the value of `$scope.formData.program_id`

Comment: Thank you that did exactly what I was wanting.